What is the proper way to call a parent's class method inside a class method?
I have a parent class that can be initialized in multiple ways. In order to do so I created an __init__ method that initializes the class in the standard way, and a class method that allows one to initialize it in the alternative way with different types of arguments. I have another class that inherits from this class. I would like to implement the same sort of structure, with alternative ways to initialize the class, i.e. have an __init__ method and a class method. Ideally I would like to re-use the class method of the parent class. However, it seems that calling it with the super() method does not work, and I have resorted to calling it directly.
I have produced a working example of my issue below, where the Rectangle class is the parent class and the Square class is the child class. The with_vectors method is the alternative class method for initialization. I have tried implementing a with_vectors class method in the Square class to call upon the with_vectors method of the parent class, but the only way this works is by calling it directly.
What am I not understanding about the super() function? Is the way I fixed it the proper way or is there some other way?
def scalar_product(vector_a: tuple, vector_b: tuple):
    if len(vector_a) != len(vector_b):
        raise ValueError(f"The vectors provided do not have the same dimensionality.")
    return (np.array(vector_a) * np.array(vector_b)).sum()


class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, side: float, width: float):
        self.side = side
        self.width = width

    @classmethod
    def with_vectors(cls, vector_a: tuple, vector_b: tuple):
        if scalar_product(vector_a, vector_b) != 0:
            raise ValueError(f"The vectors must be orthogonal")
        side = np.sqrt((np.array(vector_a) ** 2).sum())
        width = np.sqrt((np.array(vector_b) ** 2).sum())
        return cls(side, width)

    def get_area(self):
        return self.side * self.width

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, side: float):
        super().__init__(side, side)

    @classmethod
    def with_vectors(cls, vector_a: tuple):
        vector_b = (vector_a[1], -vector_a[0])
        # return super().with_vectors(vector_a, vector_b)   # TypeError: Square.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
        # return super(Rectangle, cls).with_vectors(vector_a, vector_b)   # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'with_vectors'
        return Rectangle.with_vectors(vector_a, vector_b)  # Does work


Your class method does not use parameter cls . I don't know what you need to do to define a class method.

I recommend you to redesign your classes, the main problem is that you have class method with constructor functionality with overriding requirement. I would suggest make a kind of (global) factory  function

you could use cls.__bases__[0].with_vectors(...) to call the parent class method from the child class method... but then it will returns a Rectangle object:P

you can hardcode return Rectangle(side, width) in the parent and use return super().with_vectors(vector_a, vector_b) in the child... to get a Rectangle object out of a Square

this question could be slightly related

@cards Thank you for your answers. As my real life example calls for a third level of inheritance and makes the constructor functionality even more convoluted, I believe that you may be right and that I should look at a different design for my class (using factory functions)

Calling super().with_vectors(vector_a, vector_b) from Square.with_vectors does work to invoke Rectangle.with_vectors(vector_a, vector_b), but you're getting an error of:
TypeError: Square.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

because Rectangle.with_vectors tries to create a new instance of Square with cls(side, width), where cls is Square, but Square.__init__ does not accept the width argument, hence the error.
You can work around this issue by making the signature of Square.__init__ compatible with Rectangle.__init__ with a redundant width argument, while adding a validation to make sure that width is equal to side when given:
class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, side: float, width: Optional[float] = None):
        if width is not None and width != side:
            raise ValueError('The side and width of a Square must be equal')
        super().__init__(side, side)

